# meet Call to undefined function Xinax\LaravelGettext\bindtextdomain() error in LaravelProject

Tags: laravel, docker

1.Put laraDock to laravel project.

2.And type command `docker-compose up -d nginx workspace php-fpm mysql`

3.And edit docker-compose.yml, so access to browser(192.168.99.100),
but I meet the  error`(/var/www/vendor/xinax/laravel-gettext/src/Xinax/LaravelGettext/Gettext.php line 195でCall to undefined function Xinax\LaravelGettext\bindtextdomain())`

Are there Someone who meet about same situation?
If there are, please tell me solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your php is missing this extension - `php-gettext extension`.

You need the [`php-gettext extension`](http://php.net/manual/en/gettext.installation.php) installed

And get this added to your `php.ini`:

```
extension=gettext.so
```

> See this [issue on Github](https://github.com/xinax/laravel-gettext/issues/53)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need to install an extension called `php-gettext`

you can refer this for installation : http://php.net/manual/en/gettext.installation.php

and then add this line in your active php.ini file

```
extension=gettext.so
```

Comment: @kapki.dev Thanks for answer. But I already write one to /etc/php.ini. Should I write to laradock/php-fpm/laravel.ini?